# What is the simplest way to repeat a test case without spamming the code?

Tags: selenium-ide

I'm having a really hard time trying to loop this script.

I have sideflow.js added as an extension. How do I make this loop infinitely?

I figured this feature was included lol.

```
<tr>
<td>waitForElementPresent</td>
<td>//span[@id='update-content-professions-overview-0']/span/div/div/ul/li[5]/span/div/div[4]/div[3]/button</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>click</td>
<td>//span[@id='update-content-professions-overview-0']/span/div/div/ul/li[5]/span/div/div[4]/div[3]/button</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>waitForElementPresent</td>
<td>css=#modal_content &gt; div.input-field.button &gt; button</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>click</td>
<td>css=#modal_content &gt; div.input-field.button &gt; button</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Beginning:

```
<tr>
    <td>store</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>var1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>while</td>
    <td>${var1}&lt;20</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Code Here

End:

```
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>value of var1 is ${var1}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>new Number(storedVars['var1']) + 1</td>
    <td>var1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>endWhile</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

This will repeat the Test Case 20 times.